# What is wrong with this SQL Query and how to possibly fix it?

Tags: mysql, sql

The Idea of the Query is to get all the entries where the `seo_path_info` has duplicates and the corresponding product is set to active.

My Query is:

```
SELECT `seo_path_info`,COUNT(`seo_path_info`)
FROM `shopware`.`seo_url` seo
GROUP BY `seo_path_info`
HAVING COUNT(`seo_path_info`)>1
LEFT JOIN product p ON p.id = seo.foreign_key WHERE p.active = '1';
```

And the corresponding Error:

> Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN product p ON p.id = seo.foreign_key WHERE p.active = '1'' at line 5

Comment: Reading a basic SQL tutorial would have helped...

Answer (score 5):

`JOIN` comes after `FROM` but before `WHERE`, and `WHERE` comes before `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT seo_path_info, COUNT(seo_path_info)
FROM shopware.seo_url seo
LEFT JOIN product p
    ON p.id = seo.foreign_key AND p.active = '1'
GROUP BY seo_path_info
HAVING COUNT(seo_path_info) > 1;
```

Comment: Good answer.  This can be improved by mentioning that the `WHERE` clause against `p` will break the `LEFT JOIN` behavior, removing any natural `NULL`s from the result, assuming the OP really wants outer join behavior.  Just move that logic into the `ON` clause.  If not, he shouldn't use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @JonArmstrong Agreed, I have updated my answer.  But maybe the OP really just wanted an inner join, in which case my previous version would also have been just fine.

Comment: Is it also somehow possible to only show Results, where the 'seo_path' is different?

So for example i want to have all Results where Count (seo_path_info) > 1 and seo_path is unique.

Right now I get such Results:
seo_path                 seo_path_info
/detail/1234            /product1.html
/detail/1234            /product1.html

What I really want is to find something like this:
seo_path                 seo_path_info
/detail/1234            /product1.html
/detail/2345            /product1.html

Where different Products map to one seo_path_info

Comment: @MeleeMid Best to either update the question or ask two different questions.  This doesn't make sense based on your `GROUP BY`.  Adjust the question or add a new one. If there's specific data that gives you trouble, add that to the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Basic SQL syntax is

```
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
JOIN ... ON ... 
WHERE ... 
GROUP BY ... 
HAVING...
```

The solution is:

```
SELECT seo_path_info,COUNT(seo_other_column)
FROM shopware.seo_url seo 
LEFT JOIN product p ON p.id = seo.foreign_key 
WHERE p.active = '1'
GROUP BY seo_path_info 
HAVING COUNT(seo_other_column)>1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

where caluse can't be before group by or having clause. The following would be the correct order

```
SELECT
FROM
JOIN
ON
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
ORDER BY
LIMIT
```

OR

```
SELECT
FROM
JOIN
ON
WHERE
QUALIFY -- IF YOU ARE USING A WINDOWS FUNCTION INSTED OF GROUP BY
ORDER BY
LIMIT
```